# Rewrite /SUBDIRECTORY to /subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, uppercase, lowercase

I want to make it so that if a visitor navigates to:

```
http://www.website.com/folder
```

They get redirected to:

```
http://www.website.com/FOLDER
```

It is only for this specific folder that I want to affect (or intend to).

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /FOLDER/
RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ /FOLDER$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I don't think that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ /FOLDER$1 [L,R=301]
```

should be good enough. You don't need the rewrite base but I don't think that'll affect it.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work for me, but the page that comes up is a 404 page that exists in my **domain** root and not the subdomain root. Its one of those HTML5 boilerplate 404 pages.

Comment: But I think Rewritebase still gives the same result.